# (Spring security) Page doesn't have access to css style, plugins etc. in Admin Authority

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have problem with Spring Security.. I've made a admin role for access to users section and if someone else than Admin want to go there I am redictering to 403 page and it works, but css, plugins and bootstrap are not visible from this context..

Error in browser console if not administrator wants to go there:
(403 page is displaying without bootstrap and css..)
http://prntscr.com/h497qo

Error if administrator wants to go there (no mapping)..
(users page is displaying without bootstrap and css..)
http://prntscr.com/h49b7g

Spring security config:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/bootstrap/**", "/dist/**", "/plugins/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().rememberMe()
            .tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 31).rememberMeParameter("remember-me").key("uniqueAndSecret").and()
            .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error")
            .and().csrf().disable();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
 @Override
 public void configure( WebSecurity web ) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers( "/bootstrap/**", "/dist/**", "/plugins/**");
}
```

in you security configuration.

**EDIT : ResourceHandler**

Add explicitly your static resources :

```
@Configuration
public class WebViewConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry ) {
    registry.addResourceHandler( "/bootstrap/**", "/dist/**", "/plugins/**" ).addResourceLocations( "classpath:static/bootstrap/", "classpath:static/dist/", "classpath:static/plugins/" );
  }
}
```

Note that I suppose you have those folders (`dist`, `bootstrap`, `plugins`) in your classpath under static folder.

Comment: I saw that you have an xml file, `main-servlet.xml`, consider define your static resources in that file if it defines your servlet context.

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I have to make mapping for every permission: i.e   <mvc:resources mapping="/bootstrap/**" location="/bootstrap/" />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/admin/bootstrap/**" location="/bootstrap/" />

Answer (score -1):

try this  to fix problem 'no mapping found for':

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```